# what's going on with tor?

Tags: configuration

```
root@kali:~# tor
Feb 02 07:18:55.029 [notice] Tor 0.4.2.5 running on Linux with Libevent 2.1.11-stable, OpenSSL 1.1.1d, Zlib 1.2.11, Liblzma 5.2.4, and Libzstd 1.4.4.
Feb 02 07:18:55.029 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
Feb 02 07:18:55.029 [notice] Read configuration file "/etc/tor/torrc".
Feb 02 07:18:55.030 [warn] /var/lib/tor/hidden_service is not owned by this user (root, 0) but by debian-tor (131). Perhaps you are running Tor as the wrong user?
Feb 02 07:18:55.030 [warn] Failed to parse/validate config: Failed to configure rendezvous options. See logs for details.
Feb 02 07:18:55.030 [err] Reading config failed--see warnings above.
```

Comment: What command did you use to start Tor? Tor should not be run as root which is what you did according to the output that you pasted.

Answer (score 1):

You are not starting tor properly, try to start it as a service so that it runs as the correct user.

```
# systemctl start tor
```